# MVC layered architecture using entities convertible to 'System.IDisposable'?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, idisposable, entities

My code has an error, I do not know what is causing it

```
namespace cms.data.System
{
    public class MenuProccess
    {
        public static List<ModelMenu> GetMenus(Nullable<int> LanguageID){

        using (cmsEntities db = new cmsEntities) //error on this line
        {
            return null;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

the error is

> 'cmsEntities': Type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

Comment: cmsEntities does not implement `System.IDisposable`

Comment: If cmsEntities is derived from DataContext then see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508031/entity-framework-5-model-first-where-is-idisposable-gone)  _"… your problem is most likely that your model is defined in a separate assembly that references EF5 and you have not added an EF5 reference to your project"_

Comment: `Nullable<int>` is replaceable with `int?` by the way!

Answer (score 3):

When we use a `using` statement

```
using(var a = new ClassName())
{

}
```

the `ClassName` or whatever class you use there should implement the `IDisposable` interface. That being said, it's obvious that `cmsEntities` doesn't implement this interface.

Answer (score 2):

The cmsEntities class must be implement IDisposable interface for use of "using" statement.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be the project name change.

I sat and I cried.
I created a new project.
I started again.
Thank God I started the project today.
I did not go too far.

Thank you :)